# Colorbar breaks axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the problem that a colorbar breaks the scaling of my axis, and I have no idea why. Consider the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize = (8,6/Φ), sharey=True,gridspec_kw={"width_ratios":[1,1, 0.05]})
(ax1,ax2,cax) = axes

x_ = np.linspace(-1,0,350)
y_ = np.linspace(0,1,350)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x_,y_,indexing = "ij")

dq = -Y/X
dq[dq>1] = 1

im1 = ax1.pcolormesh(X, Y*1e28, (1+dq)*1e12, vmin=0, vmax=2e12,cmap = "inferno",)

im2 = ax2.pcolormesh(X, Y*1e28, (1-dq)*1e12, vmin=0, vmax=2e12,cmap = "inferno")

plt.show()
```

which creates

[image: Figure 1]

Now, I add a colorbar as following

```
fig.colorbar(im1,  cax=cax)
```

I get the following result

[image: Figure 2]

Can you tell me what goes wrong here?! Also note the funny bug that the 1e28 of the y-axis has been replaced by a 1e12!

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are sharing the plot axes with the colorbar axes. This is not useful since they would in general be scaled very differently.

Use `sharey=False` to obtain the desired plot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have not thought about that possibility.